# CreateThread's threadProc race condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to spawn 4 threads, that basically do the same thing but with a different variable each. So I call ::CreateThread 4 times, giving the same threadProc and 'this' as a parameter. Now in threadProc, I need to pick the right variable to work with. I have a vector of objects, and I push into it the object immediately after each of the CreateThread call.

```
// at this point myVec has say, 2 items
HANDLE hThread = ::CreateThread( NULL, NULL, threadProc, (LPVOID)this, NULL, NULL );
myVecObj.threadHandle = hThread;
myVec.push_back(myVecObj); // myVec.Size = 3 now

DWORD CALLBACK myClass::threadProc(LPVOID lpContext)
{
     myClass *pMyClass = (myClass *)lpContext;
     int vecCount = pMyClass->myVec.size; // Is this 3??
     char * whatINeed = (char*)pMyClass->myVec[vecCount-1].whatINeed;
}
```

My doubt/question is how fast does the threadProc fire - could it beat the call to *myVec.push_back()*? Is this a race condition that I'm introducing here? I'm trying to make the assumption that when each threadProc starts (they start at different times, not one after the other), I can safely take the last object in the class' vector.

Comment: use `_beginthreadex()` and global scope f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to spawn 4 threads, that basically do the same thing but with a different variable each. So I call `::CreateThread` 4 times, giving the same `threadProc` and `this` as a parameter.
>
> Now in `threadProc`, I need to pick the right variable to work with.

Why not pass the thread a pointer to the actual object it needs to act on?

> I have a vector of objects, and I push into it the object immediately after each of the `CreateThread` call.

That is the wrong way to handle this.  And yes, that is a race condition.  Not only for the obvious reason - the thread might start running before the object is pushed - but also because *any* push into a vector can potentially reallocate the internal array of the vector, which would be very bad for threads that have already obtained a pointer to their data inside the vector.  The data would move around in memory behind the thread's back.

To solve this, you need to either:

1. push all of the objects into the vector first, then start your threads.  You can pass a pointer to each vector element to its respective thread.  But this works only if you don't modify the vector anymore while any thread is running, for the reason stated above.
2. start the threads in a suspended state first, and then resume them after you have pushed all the objects into the vector.  This also requires that you don't modify the vector anymore.  It also means you will have to pass each thread an index to a vector element, rather than passing it a pointer to the element.
3. get rid of the vector altogether (or at least change it to hold object pointers instead of actual objects).  Dynamically allocate your objects using `new` and pass those pointers to each thread (and optionally to the vector) as needed.  Let each thread `delete` its object before exiting (and optionally remove it from the vector, with proper synchronizing).

> My doubt/question is how fast does the `threadProc` fire

That is entirely up to the OS scheduler to decide.

> could it beat the call to `myVec.push_back()`?

Yes, that is a possibility.

> Is this a race condition that I'm introducing here?

Yes.

> I'm trying to make the assumption

Don't make assumptions!

> that when each `threadProc` starts (they start at different times, not one after the other), I can safely take the last object in the class' vector.

That is not a safe assumption to make.

Comment: Great answer. Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

There is no synchronisation between the modification of `myVec`, i.e., the `myVec.push_back()` call, and reading the size of the object in another thread. I do realise that you don't use standard threads but applying the C++11 rules there is a data race and the program has undefined behaviour.

Note that the data race isn't just theoretical: there is a fair chance that you see the modification happen after the read. Creating a thread may not be fast but some implementations actually don't create OS level threads but rather keep a pool of threads around which are used when apparently spawning a new thread.

In similar contexts I heard the excellent argument "... but it only happens once in a million times!". This particular issue would have happened on the 48 core machine about 10 times per second, assuming the estimate "once in a million" were correct.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely meant to add synchronization on myVec -- but that won't help the issue that I'm having, then. Guess I need to find a better way of differentiating between the different threadProc calls.